# Parallel Vectors and Coefficients of $\mu$

Tags: vectors

I have a question that states the following

Given that **c** = 3**i** + 4**j** and **d** = **i** - 2**j**, find μ if μ**c** + **d** is parallel to **i** + 3**j**

So I wrote the following
$$ c = \begin{pmatrix}  3\\ 4\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
$$ d = \begin{pmatrix}  1\\ -2\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

I then wrote 
$$ \mu \textbf{c} + \textbf{d} =\mu\begin{pmatrix}  3\\ 4\\ \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}  1\\ -2\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$$= \begin{pmatrix}  3\mu + 1\\ 4\mu-2\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Now I thought that if this is parallel to **i** + 3**j** then from above,

$$3\mu + 1 = 3(4\mu -2)$$

but the answer says that, in fact $$4(3\mu + 1) = 4\mu -2$$

I am confused. Why is this?
Wouldn't that imply that it is parallel to 3**i** + **j**?

The answer, strangely is given as such

[image]

Comment: two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$  are parallel if $\vec{a}=k\cdot \vec{b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation, we have a vector 
$$\mathbf a= \begin {pmatrix}a_1\\a_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}1\\3 \end{pmatrix}$$ so a  vector parallel to $\mathbf a$ is of the form
$$
\mathbf b =\begin {pmatrix}b_1\\b_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}b_1\\3b_1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Apply this to 
$$ \mathbf b=\begin {pmatrix}b_1\\b_2 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin {pmatrix}3\mu+1\\4\mu -2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
we have

$$
b_2=3b_1 \iff 4\mu -2=3(3\mu +1)
$$

Comment: yes so I said that 3μ+1=3(4μ−2) but why is that wrong?

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: I see where you have come from, but my question is why my method does not work?

Comment: because you have write that the first component is three times the second, but the correct relation is that the second is three times the first.

Comment: OH MY GOD YES THANK YOU SO MUCH please upvote my post and have a nice day